# C# UTF8Encoding getString(Byte [] ) method not appearing

Tags: c#, utf-8

I am using  Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8 with Net Framework 4.5 installed.

 I can't seem to find the getString(Byte[]) method in UTF8Encoding class.

I am not sure what I am missing since there were two methods provided in the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx).

 The method : GetString in UTF8Encoding class 

 My Microsoft **C#**  code :

```
using System.Text;

// the code which I use the GetString method
// characters is a byte array


UTF8Encoding utfEncode= new UTF8Encoding();
string encodedStr= utfEncode.GetString(characters, 0, characters.Length);   //this method is available to me 
string encodedStr= utfEncode.GetString(characters);  // the error message was that no such overloading method is found
```

Comment: What type are characters object?

Comment: Are doing XNA or portable application? if then only the first method available for you

Comment: Can you compile your code with utfEncode.GetString?

Comment: @Garath I have not run it, but the issue is I can't find that(GetString (Byte[])) method.

Comment: @Damith Trying to write it to XML from a metro app

Comment: @Adamy It gives me the error message I stated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS MSDN documentation `GetString` with one parameter not available for portable class library and XNA applications. You have to use 2nd overload with 3 parameters

[image]

Comment: And how would you use this method with 3 parameters in this scenario?